# how to add the directory containing `sci_mpi_mp.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

Tags: fortran, pkg-config

When I compile the code using `Intel compiler 13`, I met the following error:

```
pkg-config error:
Package sci_mpi_mp was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sci_mpi_mp.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sci_mpi_mp' found
```

and `which pkg-config` gives me the dir `/usr/bin/pkg-config`. So, how do I add it to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting environment variables depends on your [shell](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-what-shell-im-using.html):

**bash** `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/bin/pkg-config`

**csh** `setenv PKG_CONFIG_PATH /usr/bin/pkg-config`

Check your shell manual.

But it is more likely that the file `sci_mpi_mp.pc` is missing on your computer.